# video editing like Aviary image editing or Instagram app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am developing one application that upload videos with different effects as per show in image. now i want to edit the video same as image editing in Aviary SDK  or instagram appliction.

Is any framework available for video editing in objective c?

[image: Aviary image Effects screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

By editing do you mean filters? Try [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). Best one you can get for free.

Comment: Thanks for response. But it is for image only not for video. I tried it. It converts first frame only not an entire video.

Comment: ...you process the video a frame at a time. `GPUImage` does support video, it's one of the benchmarks.